# Filebeat configuration file troubles

Tags: kubernetes, filebeat, elk

I have installed elasticsearch, kibana and filebeat on kubernetes cluster version 7.6.1 within separate namespace.
My main goal was gather logs from other two namespaces within this cluster.
But still I have troubles with filebeat configuration file. I need to read logs from all pods of these namespaces. I have tried many configs and unfortunately it doesn't work well (gathers logs only from one namespace and/or from few pods).
I am new in that direction, so I hope I made stupid mistake and You can help me)

Below is one of many configs I have tried:

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: kubernetes
      templates:
        - condition:
            contains:
              kubernetes.namespace: "namespace-1"
          config:
            - type: container
              paths:
                - "/var/lib/docker/containers/${data.kubernetes.container.id}/${data.kubernetes.container.id}-json.log"
        - condition:
            contains:
              kubernetes.namespace: "namespace-2"
          config:
            - type: container
              paths:
                - "/var/lib/docker/containers/${data.kubernetes.container.id}/${data.kubernetes.container.id}-json.log"
```

Thank you in advance)

Comment: have you tried type: docker? https://gist.github.com/exekias/f8b0b300966fa148ac239ffaa70b5721

Comment: yes, i have. But I need to specify two namespaces. Two conditions doesn't work in my case. Can I specify two namespaces within one condition?